# Is there an equivalent in Leiningen to `clj -m`

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Is there an equivalent in Leiningen to this `clj` command :

```sh
clj -m project.core
```

Looks like if I use Leiningen I need to create `project.clj` before I could  run it with

```sh
lein run -m project.core
```

Could I run it without creating `project.clj` ?

*Example of the project which doesn't have `project.clj` file:
https://github.com/mogenslund/microliquid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible. I've tried running commands like

```
lein run -m test/-main
```

And I get errors that [suggest it can't find a main](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2091). Looking through `lein help`, pretty much everything, including things like `lein clean`, throw errors if a `project.clj` isn't found.

In the [tutorial for leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#leiningen-projects) is the chunk:

> Leiningen **works with projects**. A project is a directory containing a group of Clojure (and possibly Java) source files, **along with a bit of metadata about them. The metadata is stored in a file named project.clj in the project's root directory**, which is how you tell Leiningen about things like
>
> ...
>
> **Most Leiningen tasks only make sense in the context of a project**. Some (for example, repl or help) can also be called from any directory.

Emphasis mine.

It seems leiningen is project focused, and is expecting the meta-data held in a `project.clj` to function.

Answer (score -1):

Leiningen requires a `project.clj` file. You have to specify the namespace that contains the `-main` function there using the `:main` key. Then you can use `lein run` to start the app. A complete `project.clj` should look as follows:

```
(defproject foo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]]
  :main microliquid.core)
```